# Inserting list records in database with stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, winforms, list, stored-procedures, sqlclient

I have a list of records inserting into a SQL Server database using a stored procedure. Currently I am doing it this way but is there any better way?

I am inserting 100-200 rows per/sec on peak hours of my app. The stored procedure only gets the values and inserts the new row

```
    public void InsertRecords(List<stRecord> records)
    {
        foreach (var item in records)
        {
            if (CheckforDuplicateRecord(item) == false)
            {
                using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new    SqlCommand(StoredProcedures.Service_Insert_record.ToString(), con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@item1", SqlDbType.NChar);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@item2", SqlDbType.NChar);

                    cmd.Parameters[0].Value = item.localUsername;
                    cmd.Parameters[1].Value = item.BetfairUsername;


                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception exp)
                    {
                        throw exp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking for better performance, code improvements, either or?

Comment: Both Way if possible ., i am very new in C# i dont know if its the Right Way of coding , As suppose we have 200 Records and We are Opening DB connection 200 time and then closing it and inserting record one by by , inst there be some better coding ? for both memory improvements or permanence

Comment: Which version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: @user353600 I'm not an authority on the subject, so I hesitate to post an answer.  However, I believe `cmd.Parameters.Add()` is deprecated, I think you ought to use `AddWithValue()`.  You could also wrap your SqlCommand object in a `using` statement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is exactly what table-valued parameters are for - you can pass your list in one shot.

In SQL Server:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Usernames AS TABLE
(
  localUsername   NVARCHAR(32),
  BetfairUsername NVARCHAR(32)
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Service_Insert_MultipleRows
  @u AS dbo.Usernames READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT INTO dbo.DestinationTable(localUsername, BetfairUsername)
    SELECT localUsername, BetfairUsername FROM @u;
END
GO
```

Now in C#:

```
DataTable tvp = new DataTable();
tvp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("localUsername"));
tvp.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BetfairUsername"));

foreach(var item in records)
{ 
    tvp.Rows.Add(item.localUsername, item.BetfairUsername); 
}

using (con)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Service_Insert_MultipleRows", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter tvparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u", tvp);
    tvparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Absolutely. You're making exactly one connection to the database, calling a procedure once, and sending the data over as a single stream.

Comment: i am working on thing and it seems the most Clean and Beautiful Code , i will let you know with results

Comment: Just here to add that you do not need to type `new DataColumn()`, passing only a string will automatically create a `DataColumn` with that name

Answer (score 0):

One obvious thing you could do: create the `SqlCommand` only **once** at the beginning of the method - no point in creating it over and over and over again!

```
public void InsertRecords(List<stRecord> records)
{
   using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedures.Service_Insert_record.ToString(), con))
   {
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       // are those paramters *REALLY* just 1 character long?? 
       // that's what you have now, with the way you define it!
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@item1", SqlDbType.NChar);
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@item2", SqlDbType.NChar);

       // otherwise, you need to define the LENGTH of the NCHAR parameter!
       // cmd.Parameters.Add("@item2", SqlDbType.NChar, 15);

       foreach (var item in records)
       {
           if (CheckforDuplicateRecord(item) == false)
           {
              cmd.Parameters["@item1"].Value = item.localUsername;
              cmd.Parameters["@item2"].Value = item.BetfairUsername;

              try
              {
                 con.Open();
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 con.Close();
              }
              catch (Exception exp)
              {
                 throw;
              }
            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: isn't there anything wrong with opening connection 200 times ? in 1 second ? and this happens continuously as it is a web service

Comment: @user353600: ADO.NET connection are pooled, so "opening" and "closing" them isn't a really big operation at all. But yes - you might also try to open the connection before the `foreach` - that just makes the error handling in case of an exception a bit more complicated....